# Getting KeyError when saving style multiindex pandas to excel

Tags: python, pandas, styles

When saving a `df` that has been style into excel, compiler return

> KeyError: "['A'] not in index"

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def color_negative_red(value):
  if value < 0:
    color = 'red'
  elif value > 0:
    color = 'green'
  else:
    color = 'black'

  return 'color: %s' % color

np.random.seed(0)
arrays = [np.hstack([['One']*2, ['Two']*2]) , ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays)
df=  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.columns = columns
data=df.style.applymap(color_negative_red, subset=['A'])

data.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

Expected output

[image]

P.S.: Similar post has been submitted to pandas git: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42906 for a potential bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with `Styler.to_excel`. It is to do with the fact you are using a MultiIndex columns and not supplying a `subset` in a valid format.

As advised in the docs you must supply a valid `.loc` indexer.

The solution is to use:

```py
df.style.applymap(color_negative_red, subset=(slice(None), (slice(None), 'A')))
```

or pandas Indexer if you prefer (these solutions are isomorphic)

```py
ix = pd.IndexSlice
df.style.applymap(color_negative_red, subset=ix[:, ix[:, 'A']])
```

Note your output will affect only the text color because you have not used the `background-color` CSS attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try that:

```
df.style.applymap(color_negative_red, subset=([slice(None), "A"]))
```

Comment: Thanks for dropping by @Coralien. Compiler throw :`NotImplementedError: Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented` when implementing you suggestion